# MySQL: sort order "SHOW TABLES"

Tags: mysql, sql

How are the tables ordered returned by "SHOW TABLES"?

For example the output for the `information_schema` database looks like this:

```
CHARACTER_SETS
COLLATIONS
COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY
COLUMNS
COLUMN_PRIVILEGES
ENGINES
EVENTS
FILES
GLOBAL_STATUS
GLOBAL_VARIABLES
KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
PARAMETERS
PARTITIONS
PLUGINS
PROCESSLIST
PROFILING
REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
ROUTINES
SCHEMATA
SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES
SESSION_STATUS
SESSION_VARIABLES
STATISTICS
TABLES
TABLESPACES
TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
TABLE_PRIVILEGES
TRIGGERS
USER_PRIVILEGES
VIEWS
INNODB_CMP_RESET
INNODB_TRX
INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET
INNODB_LOCK_WAITS
INNODB_CMPMEM
INNODB_CMP
INNODB_LOCKS
```

Comment: I think like any other table. The order is not guaranteed, it is a set. Not a cursor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See Sergei Golubchik's answer from [SHOW DATABASES does not order infomation_schema correct](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=14473): "no SHOW command sorts the result".

If you need the tables names sorted you can query `information_schema.tables`, something like:

```
select table_name from information_schema.tables 
 where table_schema = 'your_db_name' order by table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'information_schema' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code works pretty well for me to list specific tables on any of my database and sort them by their name as asked.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_database_here' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE '%letters_from_your_table_here%' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME DESC
```